# Get only newly emitted values

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular app I'm using `ngxs` library as my store.
I have method that gets `last edited id`:

```js
return this.store.select((state: AppStateModel) => state.lastEditedId)
      .pipe(filter(id => id > 0));
```

I'm using it for changing option in form. Like this:

```js
this._options$ = merge(
      /**
       * Init value from query param
       */
      initValue$.pipe(tap(i => console.log('initValue$', i)), take(1)),
      /**
       * Last edited id
       * Here I want only newly emitted values, but I also get old one.
       */
      this.obiektySelectors.lastEditedId()
        .pipe(
          tap(i => console.log('lastEditedId', i)),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
        ),
);
```

Problem is that when I have value in `lastEditedId` it always gets to `this._options$` stream. I know that it was not emitted.
Can I force observable to take only emitted values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only idea that comes to my head is to create separate subject which will subscribe to `lastEditedId()` and reemit id's.

```js
const idChanges = new Subject();
this.obiektySelectors.lastEditedId().subscribe(id => idChanges.next(id));
```

Then you can use this subject in your merge. Because `Subject` doesn't store last value it'will emit only new ids.

```js
this._options$ = merge(
      /* ... */
      idChanges
        .pipe(
          tap(i => console.log('lastEditedId', i)),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
        ),
);
```

little improvised demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8vugyz